# Prove that $X\times X$ is path connected .

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove that : $(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}) \backslash  (\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q})$ is path connected.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 5):

The English term is actually *path connected*. Here’s a hint. If $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle\in(\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\setminus(\Bbb Q\setminus\Bbb Q)$, there is a path in $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\setminus(\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q)$ connecting $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ of one of the following kinds:

- a vertical line segment;
- a horizontal line segment;
- the union of a vertical and a horizontal line segment;
- the union of two vertical and one horizontal line segments;
- the union of one vertical and two horizontal line segments.

Remember, a point in the plane is in $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\setminus(\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q)$ if and only if at least one of its coordinates is irrational.

Comment: @HungNguyen: You’re welcome.

Comment: @user14111: No real harm done: yours is a different argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the term "line connected" but I'm guessing it means that any two points can be connected by a polygonal line. (I would have called that "polygonally connected".)  To prove that $(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)\setminus(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)$ is line connected observe that, given two distinct points $P,Q\in(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)\setminus(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)$, we can draw continuum many internally disjoint polygonal lines from $P$ to $Q$. Most simply, let $l$ be the perpendicular bisector of the segment $PQ$, and for each point $R$ on $l$ take the path $PR+RQ$. These paths are pairwise disjoint except for the  endpoints $P$ and $Q$. Since $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ is countable, most of those paths are disjoint from $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$.

P.S. The same argument shows that $(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)\setminus D$ is polygonally connected for any countable set $D$, more generally, for any set $D$ whose cardinality is less than the continuum.